# regex multiple lines and store results in an array iteratively

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, regex, pandas, loops

I have a bank statement and have used Regex to extract all the items in a table. 
The list is

```
['15-10-2019 BIL/INFT/001823982708/Block2B5/ MAHAK JUNEJA 5,130.00 5,19,319.08',
 '15-10-2019 BIL/INFT/001824120963/watermaintoct/ AAANKSHA AGRAWA 3,895.00 5,23,214.08',
 '15-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING MMT/IMPS/928820560895/VURIMI UMA/AXIS BANK LTD 5,201.00 5,28,415.08',
 '15-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING MMT/IMPS/928820342293/B1H2/KAVURI KIS/HDFC BANK LTD 3,401.00 5,31,816.08',
 '15-10-2019 SE EER TRS 2 Malntenen eee guna. Shula HEEGBAME 3,732.00 5,35,548.08',
 '16-10-2019 CHEQUE 7048 CLG/ZAP POWER SYSTEMS/UBI 16,815.00 5,18,733.08',
 '17-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING NANCE ee osnesiBers GGRA fee/VOONA SRIN/HDFC 500.00 5,19,233.08',
 '18-10-2019 CHEQUE 7049 CLG/BANGALORE APARTMENTS FED/SBI 3,500.00 5,15,733.08',
 '21-10-2019 CHEQUE 7054 CASH PAID:mohan 1075 BANGALORE-BELLANDUR VILLAGE 20,000.00 4,95,733.08',
 '24-10-2019 CHEQUE 7052 CLG/V PRAVEEN RAM/YES 14,000.00 4,81,733.08',
 '25-10-2019 CHEQUE 7051 CLG/BESCOM S/UTI 17,385.00 4,64,348.08',
 '30-10-2019 107510010791I0 Int on FD/RD XXX0791 Tds:0.Int:8625 and TAX:0. 8,625.00 4,72,973.08',
 '31-10-2019 CHEQUE 7055 CLG/ADVANCE ENGINEERING CORPORATION/HSB 14,337.00 4,58,636.08']
```

I need to store them in this format:

```
Date        Item                           Name         Amount    Total       
15-10-2019  BIL/INFT/001823982708/Block2B5 MAHAK JUNEJA 5,130.00  5,19,319.08
```

for every line in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a named tuple, "Transaction", inside a list, you can collect all data albeit Item and Name still needs more clarity for regex separation:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re

l = [
    "15-10-2019 BIL/INFT/001823982708/Block2B5/ MAHAK JUNEJA 5,130.00 5,19,319.08",
    "15-10-2019 BIL/INFT/001824120963/watermaintoct/ AAANKSHA AGRAWA 3,895.00 5,23,214.08",
    "30-10-2019 107510010791I0 Int on FD/RD XXX0791 Tds:0.Int:8625 and TAX:0. 8,625.00 4,72,973.08",
    "31-10-2019 CHEQUE 7055 CLG/ADVANCE ENGINEERING CORPORATION/HSB 14,337.00 4,58,636.08",
]

cols = ["Date", "Item_Name", "Amount", "Total"]

date_pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}", re.I)
item_and_name_pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s).*", re.I)
amount_pattern = re.compile(r"\d+,\d+.\d+", re.I)
total_pattern = re.compile(r"\d+,\d+,\d+.\d+$", re.I)

Transaction = namedtuple("Transaction", cols)
transactions = []

for item in l:
    date = re.search(date_pattern, item).group()
    total = re.search(total_pattern, item).group()
    temp_1 = item.rstrip(total)
    amount = re.search(amount_pattern, temp_1).group()
    temp_2 = temp_1.strip().rstrip(amount)
    item_and_name = re.search(item_and_name_pattern, temp_2).group()

    t = Transaction(date, item_and_name, amount, total)
    transactions.append(t)

for t in transactions:
    print(t)
```

Returning:

```
Transaction(Date='15-10-2019', Item_Name='BIL/INFT/001823982708/Block2B5/ MAHAK JUNEJA ', Amount='5,130.00', Total='5,19,319.08')
Transaction(Date='15-10-2019', Item_Name='BIL/INFT/001824120963/watermaintoct/ AAANKSHA AGRAWA ', Amount='3,895.00', Total='5,23,214.08')
Transaction(Date='30-10-2019', Item_Name='107510010791I0 Int on FD/RD XXX0791 Tds:0.Int:8625 and TAX:0. ', Amount='8,625.00', Total='4,72,973.08')
Transaction(Date='31-10-2019', Item_Name='CHEQUE 7055 CLG/ADVANCE ENGINEERING CORPORATION/HSB ', Amount='14,337.00', Total='4,58,636.08')
```

Comment: Thank You Gustav!! I understand that it may be a little bit of research to understand how to strip item and name. This works well. I need to insert a try catch block to escape errors where amount is not present. Any idea how to represent the result in dictionary format? Sorry, I do not have enough reputations to cast an upvote.

Comment: out = [{k:v for k, v in f._asdict().items()} for f in transactions]                  seems to do the trick of dictionary

Comment: Wow, looks nice! Sorry for late feedback

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how you want to store those values but you can use split method such as following,

```
l1=['15-10-2019 BIL/INFT/001823982708/Block2B5/ MAHAK JUNEJA 5,130.00 5,19,319.08',
 '15-10-2019 BIL/INFT/001824120963/watermaintoct/ AAANKSHA AGRAWA 3,895.00 5,23,214.08',
 '15-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING MMT/IMPS/928820560895/VURIMI UMA/AXIS BANK LTD 5,201.00 5,28,415.08',
 '15-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING MMT/IMPS/928820342293/B1H2/KAVURI KIS/HDFC BANK LTD 3,401.00 5,31,816.08',
 '15-10-2019 SE EER TRS 2 Malntenen eee guna. Shula HEEGBAME 3,732.00 5,35,548.08',
 '16-10-2019 CHEQUE 7048 CLG/ZAP POWER SYSTEMS/UBI 16,815.00 5,18,733.08',
 '17-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING NANCE ee osnesiBers GGRA fee/VOONA SRIN/HDFC 500.00 5,19,233.08',
 '18-10-2019 CHEQUE 7049 CLG/BANGALORE APARTMENTS FED/SBI 3,500.00 5,15,733.08',
 '21-10-2019 CHEQUE 7054 CASH PAID:mohan 1075 BANGALORE-BELLANDUR VILLAGE 20,000.00 4,95,733.08',
 '24-10-2019 CHEQUE 7052 CLG/V PRAVEEN RAM/YES 14,000.00 4,81,733.08',
 '25-10-2019 CHEQUE 7051 CLG/BESCOM S/UTI 17,385.00 4,64,348.08',
 '30-10-2019 107510010791I0 Int on FD/RD XXX0791 Tds:0.Int:8625 and TAX:0. 8,625.00 4,72,973.08',
 '31-10-2019 CHEQUE 7055 CLG/ADVANCE ENGINEERING CORPORATION/HSB 14,337.00 4,58,636.08']
l2=[]

#splitting values based on '/'
for i in l1:
    l2.append(i.split('/'))

#printing values from sublists of l2    
for j in l2:
    for k in j:
        print(k)
```

output:

```
15-10-2019 BIL
INFT
001823982708
Block2B5
 MAHAK JUNEJA 5,130.00 5,19,319.08
15-10-2019 BIL
INFT
001824120963
watermaintoct
 AAANKSHA AGRAWA 3,895.00 5,23,214.08
15-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING MMT
IMPS
928820560895
VURIMI UMA
AXIS BANK LTD 5,201.00 5,28,415.08
15-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING MMT
IMPS
928820342293
B1H2
KAVURI KIS
HDFC BANK LTD 3,401.00 5,31,816.08
15-10-2019 SE EER TRS 2 Malntenen eee guna. Shula HEEGBAME 3,732.00 5,35,548.08
16-10-2019 CHEQUE 7048 CLG
ZAP POWER SYSTEMS
UBI 16,815.00 5,18,733.08
17-10-2019 MOBILE BANKING NANCE ee osnesiBers GGRA fee
VOONA SRIN
HDFC 500.00 5,19,233.08
18-10-2019 CHEQUE 7049 CLG
BANGALORE APARTMENTS FED
SBI 3,500.00 5,15,733.08
21-10-2019 CHEQUE 7054 CASH PAID:mohan 1075 BANGALORE-BELLANDUR VILLAGE 20,000.00 4,95,733.08
24-10-2019 CHEQUE 7052 CLG
V PRAVEEN RAM
YES 14,000.00 4,81,733.08
25-10-2019 CHEQUE 7051 CLG
BESCOM S
UTI 17,385.00 4,64,348.08
30-10-2019 107510010791I0 Int on FD
RD XXX0791 Tds:0.Int:8625 and TAX:0. 8,625.00 4,72,973.08
31-10-2019 CHEQUE 7055 CLG
ADVANCE ENGINEERING CORPORATION
HSB 14,337.00 4,58,636.08
```

Comment: Just edited the question to illustrate the type of putput I am expecting

Comment: Your data does not contains name or other parameter's each time so  unable to sort it as you want.